# JavaScript can't convert to object JSON from Python Flask, it only sees it as a string

Tags: javascript, python, json, parsing, client-side

I am creating a dynamic JSON structure in Flask.

I convert it to string before it sent to the client:

```
json.dumps(db_list)
```

Then in the client-side it is rendered as this: (copied from View Source in Chrome):

```
<input type="hidden"
       id="data_from_server"
       name="data_from_server"
       value='[{&#39;data_source_name&#39;: &#39;FOO&#39;, &#39;db_servers_entry_list&#39;: [{&#39;yml_props&#39;: {&#39;version&#39;: 12, &#39;dir&#39;: &#39;dir/Oracle&#39;, &#39;default&#39;: True, &#39;schema&#39;: {&#39;driver&#39;: &#39;xxOracleDriver&#39;}}, &#39;display&#39;: &#39;oracle-12c-xxxx&#39;, &#39;ip&#39;: &#39;xsx&#39;, &#39;port&#39;: &#39;1521&#39;, &#39;selected&#39;: True}, {&#39;yml_props&#39;: {&#39;dir&#39;: &#39;sql-scripts/MySQL&#39;, &#39;version&#39;: 5.7}, &#39;display&#39;: &#39;mysql-5.7-xxxx-x&#39;, &#39;ip&#39;: &#39;dd.dd&#39;, &#39;port&#39;: &#39;3306&#39;, &#39;selected&#39;: False}, {&#39;yml_db&#39;: {&#39;dir&#39;: &#39;sql-scripts/MsSQL&#39;, &#39;version&#39;: 2017}, &#39;display&#39;: &#39;mssql-s&#39;, &#39;ip&#39;: &#39;10.x.x.x&#39;, &#39;port&#39;: &#39;1433&#39;, &#39;selected&#39;: False}], &#39;clean&#39;: {&#39;create&#39;: &#39;db/main.sql&#39;, &#39;polulate&#39;: [{&#39;xxxx&#39;: {&#39;enabled&#39;: True, &#39;scripts&#39;: [&#39;mssql/*-sql&#39;, &#39;clean/*.sql&#39;]}}, {&#39;xx&#39;: {&#39;enabled&#39;: True, &#39;scripts&#39;: [&#39;dir/*.sql*.sql&#39;]}}, {&#39;DI&#39;: {&#39;enabled&#39;: True, &#39;scripts&#39;: [&#39;dir/*.sql&#39;]}}]}, &#39;services:&#39;: [&#39;xxxxxxxx&#39;, &#39;xxxxxx&#39;, &#39;xxxxpm&#39;, &#39;xxxxuser&#39;]}, {&#39;data_source_name&#39;: &#39;dt&#39;, &#39;db_servers_entry_list&#39;: [{&#39;yml_db&#39;: {&#39;version&#39;: 12, &#39;default&#39;: True, &#39;schema&#39;: {&#39;driver&#39;: &#39;xxOracleDriver&#39;, &#39;user&#39;: &#39;xxx&#39;, &#39;password&#39;: &#39;yyyy&#39;, &#39;ip&#39;: &#39;10.x.x.x&#39;, &#39;port&#39;: 1541, &#39;sid&#39;: &#39;zzz&#39;, &#39;url&#39;: &#39;jdbc:oracle:thin:yyyy/yyyy@$10.x.x.x:1541/zzz&#39;}}, &#39;display&#39;: &#39;oracle-12c-xxxx&#39;, &#39;ip&#39;: &#39;xsx&#39;, &#39;port&#39;: &#39;1521&#39;, &#39;selected&#39;: True}, {&#39;yml_db&#39;: {&#39;version&#39;: 5.7}, &#39;display&#39;: &#39;mysql-5.7-xxxx-x&#39;, &#39;ip&#39;: &#39;dd.dd&#39;, &#39;port&#39;: &#39;3306&#39;, &#39;selected&#39;: False}, {&#39;yml_properties&#39;: {&#39;version&#39;: 2017}, &#39;display&#39;: &#39;mssql-s&#39;, &#39;ip&#39;: &#39;10.x.x.x&#39;, &#39;port&#39;: &#39;1433&#39;, &#39;selected&#39;: False}], &#39;clean&#39;: None, &#39;services:&#39;: [&#39;xxxxxxxx&#39;]}]'>
```

In client side when I do:

```
typeof(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("data_from_server").value)))
```

I keep getting that it is "string".

When I do:

```
typeof(JSON.parse(document.getElementById("data_from_server").value))
```

I'm getting:

```
VM3503:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:13
```

Why it is rendered with `"&#39;"`? What is wrong with my JSON?

Comment: `value` is not a json, can you show a little sample of `json.dumps(db_list)`?

Comment: its problematic to show it as it loop that build from python dict's the json 
why value is not a json ? you can see its json ....